# Add custom action in controller and call its

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add action like this:

```
  def destroy_all
    Task.destroy_all
  end
```

And I try link to this method in the view:

```
<%= link_to "delete all", controller: 'tasks', action: 'destroy_all' %>
```

And I added to my routes.rb:

```
resources :tasks
```

But when I go to my root_path I get:

```
No route matches {:action=>"destroy_all", :controller=>"tasks"}
```

But I have line resources :tasks. So I don't know what is wrong.
I just want to call my `destroy_all` action as simple as possible and return to root path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resources :tasks` does not provide a route for 'destroy_all'. You can view all of your available routes using rake:

```
$ rake routes
```

You'll see that `resources :tasks` creates some new routes:

```
               tasks GET    /tasks(.:format)               tasks#index
                     POST   /tasks(.:format)               tasks#create
            new_task GET    /tasks/new(.:format)           tasks#new
           edit_task GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format)      tasks#edit
                task GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)           tasks#show
                     PATCH  /tasks/:id(.:format)           tasks#update
                     PUT    /tasks/:id(.:format)           tasks#update
                     DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)           tasks#destroy
```

If you want to add a route for `delete_all` then you can change your resource to:

```
resources :tasks do
  collection do
    delete :delete_all
  end
end
```

Again, you can use rake to check the new route:

```
    delete_all_tasks DELETE /tasks/delete_all(.:format)    tasks#delete_all
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. But now I have problem with message: _The action 'show' could not be found for TasksController_ after click `delete all`. I used `render 'index'` in `destroy_all` action and I tried `render nothing: true`. I don't want to render anything special, only root path.

Comment: Glad that helped. That sounds like a new problem, it might be a good idea to create a new SO question so that people can see controller action code. I'll be happy to try to answer when you post a new question :)